# Same letter gives different ASCII code

Tags: java, android

I have android search query and performing filtering. All cases works exept one letter search - "ә" (kazakh language)

```
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        final List<SongModel> l = dc.songList;
        int count = l.size();
        List<SongModel> nSongList = new ArrayList<SongModel>(count);

        for (SongModel p : l) {
            if ("ә".contains(constraint.toString())) {
                nSongList.add(p);
            }
        }

        results.values = nSongList;
        results.count = nSongList.size();

        return results;
    }
```

If I enter to search field "ә" letter they are not equal in my if case.
"ә".contains(constraint.toString()) returns false.

Comment: THere is no ascii code for that letter.  Did you mean unicode codepoints?  Are you sure the letter has only one codepoint-  some have multiple.

Comment: @GabeSechan one letter has two codepoints. How can I solve this?

Comment: What is the value of int `int uniCode` = "ә";`?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @AlLelopath I found an answer : constraint = constraint.replace((char)601,(char)1241);

Comment: Glad you solved it. Post your own answer then so the question is marked as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed ASCII code of my char(letter): s.replace((char)601,(char)1241);
Because performFiltering gives me 'ә' letter as 601. Then I changed it to correct one 1241.
And now it works properly in my case.

```
@Override
protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
    FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

    final List<SongModel> l = dc.songList;
    int count = l.size();
    List<SongModel> nSongList = new ArrayList<SongModel>(count);
    String s = constraint.toString();
    s = s.replace((char)601,(char)1241);
    // or s.replace('\u0259','\u04D9');
    for (SongModel p : l) {
        if (p.getName().contains(s)) {
            nSongList.add(p);
        }
    }

    results.values = nSongList;
    results.count = nSongList.size();

    return results;
}
```

Comment: It would be far easier to understand ['\u04D9'](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/04d9/index.htm) than `(char)1241`.

Comment: The reason is that the same letter (like `a`) exists **both in latin script and cyrillic script**. It would be worth to turn your exception case handling to a more "translateLatinIntoCyrillic(ch)` - `{{'\u259', '\u04D9'}}`.

Answer (score 0):

Will this get you what you need?

```
final int uniCodeForSchwa = (int) 'ә'; // 1241
String constraint = "somecharacters";
for (int i = 0; i < constraint.length(); i++){
    char c = constraint.charAt(i);
    int intValue = Character.getNumericValue(c);
    if (uniCodeForSchwa == intValue) {
        nSongList.add(p);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: uniCodeForSchwa not always have one letter. It can be like  "әлем", "сәлем"  and so on. And I want to check if "сәлем" contains "әл"

Comment: I'm not exactly clear on what you need. It sounds like you might need to use a regular expression. Please precisely define the string or strings that you need to find for this problem.